# Adverb(?) ‘more’ in ‘more than’

Tags: phrase-meaning

> At this point signing a contract would be little **more than** a
> formality.

Does ‘more than a formality’ mean ‘very formal’?

Comment: The phrase is _little more than a formality_ - it means much the same as _only a formality_. Signing a contract now would make no practical difference to the situation, it would just make things official. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/formality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence should be parsed like this:

> Signing a contract would be
> little more than
> a formality.

[**little more than** is an idiomatic phrase that means "only slightly more than".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/little%20more%20than)

A [**formality**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formality) is "something that we do to comply with rules" or "a standard procedure that we do even though it doesn't have any effect".

So the sentence can be interpreted like this:

> Signing a contract would be **not much more than a ritual.**

Comment: What part of speech is ‘more’ in the meaning?

Comment: @himynameis  I think it's an adverb.